# Storing a Map collection of values in Enum class for better access

Tags: java, hash, enums, hashmap

I have the next `enum` class:

```
public class DataParameter {

    public enum Types {
        BIG(-1), SMALL(1), SMAL2(2), SMAL3(5), BIG1(-1), BIG2(1), BIG3(2), BIF4(
                5);

        private final int id;

        Types(int id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        public int getValue() {
            return id;
        }

        public static <T> parseType(T type, int id) {
            int intType = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(type));

            if (intType == SIZE_XL.getValue()) {
                if (id == -1)
                    return BIG;
                if (id == 1)
                    return BIG2;
                if (id == 2)
                    return BIG3;
                if (id == 5)
                    return BIG4;
            } else if (intType == SIZE_LARGE.getValue()) {
                if (id == 5)
                    return BIG4;
                if (id == 2)
                    return SMALL2;
                if (id == 5)
                    return SMALL3;
            } else if (intType == SIZE_UKNOWN.getValue()) {
                if (id == -1)
                    return BIG;
                if (id == -1)
                    return BIG;
                if (id == -1)
                    return BIG1;
                if (id == 5)
                    return BIG4;
            } else if (intType == SIZE_UKNOWN_2.getValue()) {
                return SMAL3;
            }

            return returnDefault(intType);
        }
    }

    public DataParameter(GameTypes type) {
        mValue = type.getValue();
    }
}
```

The problem that this code is very messy a lot of if statements. I tried to create a map that will be the next structure:

```
SIZE_XL ---> BIG,BIG2,BIG4
SIZE_LARGE ---> BIG4,SMALL2 ,SMALL3
SIZE_UKNOWN ---> BIG , BIG1 , BIG4
```

and them when when I'll get key I will retrieve the element from the map
I get confused because in the `enum` class I get some unknown problems.

```
HashMap<Integer, HashMap<Integer, Integer> myMap = new HashMap<Integer, HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
myMap.put(SIZE_XL.getValue(),BIG2.getValue(),BIG2)
myMap.put(SIZE_XL.getValue(),BIG3.getValue(),BIG3)
myMap.put(SIZE_XL.getValue(),BIG4.getValue(),BIG4)
```

...

...
..

I'll appreciate a help in that issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, you left out the definition of `SIZE_XL` and similar constants, I propose that instead of defining them as some constant you put them in an `enum` of their own, for example:

```
enum Size {
  XL(2), LARGE(1), UNKNOWN(-1), UNKNOWN_2(-2);

  private final int value;
  Size(int val) {
    value = val;
  }

  public int getValue() {
    return value;
  }
}
```

In your parse method you are looking up a `Types` based on two parameters, essentially these are two keys which you need to combine to get your value. `Table` is a data structure defined in [Guava](https://github.com/google/guava) with two keys (a row and a column) and one value. Storing the combinations of interest (as defined in your parse function) in an [ImmutableTable](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableTable.html) allows you to perform a quick lookup for the right value. The code becomes:

```
public enum Types {
  SMALL(1), SMALL2(2), SMALL3(3),

  BIG(0), BIG1(1), BIG2(2), BIG3(3), BIG4(4);

  static final ImmutableTable<Integer, Integer, Types> TABLE =
    ImmutableTable.<Integer, Integer, Types>builder()
      .put(Size.XL.getValue(), BIG.getValue(), BIG)
      .put(Size.XL.getValue(), BIG2.getValue(), BIG2)
      .put(Size.XL.getValue(), BIG4.getValue(), BIG4)
      .put(Size.LARGE.getValue(), BIG4.getValue(), BIG4)
      .put(Size.LARGE.getValue(), SMALL2.getValue(), SMALL2)
      .put(Size.LARGE.getValue(), SMALL3.getValue(), SMALL3)
      .put(Size.UNKNOWN.getValue(), BIG.getValue(), BIG)
      .put(Size.UNKNOWN.getValue(), BIG1.getValue(), BIG1)
      .put(Size.UNKNOWN.getValue(), BIG4.getValue(), BIG4)
      .build();

  private final int id;

  Types(int id) {
    this.id = id;
  }

  public int getValue() {
    return id;
  }

  public static Collection<Types> getTypesWithSize(Size size) {
    return TABLE.row(size.getValue()).values();
  }

  public static Collection<Types> getTypesWithId(Types types) {
    return TABLE.column(types.getValue()).values();
  }

  public static <T> Types parseType(T type, int id) {
    final int intType = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(type));

    if (!TABLE.contains(intType, id)) {
      // return some default value or throw exception
    }
    return TABLE.get(intType, id);
  }
}
```

Now you can use this code as:

```
Types.getTypesWithSize(Size.LARGE); // returns [SMALL2, BIG4, SMALL3]
Types.getTypesWithId(Types.SMALL3); // returns [SMALL3]
```

Note that I had to change some of the values for the `Types` in order to avoid duplicate row and column combinations, for a given row and column there can be only one `Types` instance.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of directly putting the values in Map you need to create a map and you would be required to put that Map against the Key from `enum`. You have currently put the values in a form which is not applicable in Map

i.e. Instead of using

```
HashMap<Integer, HashMap<Integer, Integer> myMap = new HashMap<Integer, HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
myMap.put(SIZE_XL.getValue(),BIG2.getValue(),BIG2)
```

use:

```
HashMap<Integer, HashMap<Integer, Integer> myMap = new HashMap<Integer,     HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
Map<Integer, Integer> valueMap = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();//create a map for values
valueMap.put(BIG2.getValue(), BIG2);//put the value and enum field in the value map
myMap.put(SIZE_XL.getValue(), valueMap);//put the value map against the key in your map.
```